# how to solve "generating map in other device through APK" in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on a Mapview in my android application, in which i have to show few lat long location with balloons on the map view.
It is working well in emulator and when I run thru my run configuration in my device too, but when i send the apk for other devices, the MAP view class do not generate MAP.

This problem arises only when I transfer the APK for other devices. The APK is Signed well with the authenticate signature.

Please let me know the cause of such prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I know so far for devices not showing the maps is related to the maps api key wich should be in your map layout with something like this: `android:apiKey="Your Maps API Key goes here"`
you can find the info here: [Android MapView Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) and I will quote a bit of it that might be your issue:

> For the purpose of this tutorial, you should register with the SDK
>   debug certificate, which will only be valid while your application is
>   signed with the debug key (***once you sign with your private key, you
>   will need a new API key***). When you get your key, insert it for the
>   value of android:apiKey.

Comment: Thanks alot!I was using two different signatures. I just generate a new MD5 imprint and created a new API key for MAP for my authenticated signature keystore.